# Problems with global variable Django

Tags: python, django

I write a quiz web site. And i need to save answers from users. Some of them have similar username. This is my start function

```
global new_user_answer
user_group = request.user.groups.values_list()
university = user_group[0][1]
num = Answers.objects.all().count()
new_user_answer = num + 1
new_line = Answers(id=new_user_answer, id_user=user)
new_line.save()
return redirect(f'/1')
```

Here I create new line in my DB. Second function save user answers.

```
    data = Answers.objects.get(id=new_user_answer)
    setattr(data, question, answers)
    data.save()
    if int(id_questions) < 47:
        return redirect(f'/{int(id_questions) +1 }')
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Sometime I have a error 500

```
name new_user_answer is no define
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Huh, what are you trying to do there? This approach is ridiculous and prone to breaking, Django already has fields for primary keys that increase automatically, also once you save the object you can get the pk value from it. Global variables unless you know exactly what you are doing aren't great ideas for a web server.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat every user start a quiz and save all in my DB. It is very important that each respondent has his own line. However, users can have the same username.

Comment: You seem to talking about something other than my comment above... You probably should refactor most of your code from what I see, using a count and adding one to create the next id is not needed [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#autofield) handles that out of the box on the DB side. You have: `int(id_questions) < 47` which doesn't look to be great code to me, is 47 a hardcoded ID? You probably shouldn't do that, even if not its a magic string in your code...

Comment: ... And then you have `Answers.objects.get(id=new_user_answer)` where `new_user_answer`, rather than doing this your view should probably receive the needed id in the url or as a POST parameter etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it has no sense to use a global variable on that way. You could define a session variable instead (a cookie).

Edit the MIDDLEWARE setting and make sure it contains `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware`.

#start function

```
user_group = request.user.groups.values_list()
university = user_group[0][1]
num = Answers.objects.all().count()
request.session['new_user_answer'] = num + 1
new_line = Answers(id=request.session['new_user_answer'], id_user=user)
new_line.save()
return redirect(f'/1')
```

#Second function

```
if 'new_user_answer' in request.session:
    data = Answers.objects.get(id=request.session['new_user_answer'])
    setattr(data, question, answers)
    data.save()
if int(id_questions) < 47:
    return redirect(f'/{int(id_questions) +1 }')
else:
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-object-guidelines

Comment: And what is supposed to happen when the user loses their session (logging out or any other way)? Neither global variables or the session seems like a way to do whatever OP wants to do to me.